# Copy few lines from one file to another

Tags: perl, file, copy

Here is my question let's say I have a file `file1.txt` with contents:

```
abc 
def ->[
    sff 
    ghi 
]
dqq
```

Now I want to copy all the line starting from `sff` to `ghi` from `file1.txt` to end of `file2.txt`

i.e. the following lines should added to `file2.txt`

```
sff
ghi
```

This is waht i have. Suggest me instead of "last" what should i have use to fullfill my requirement:

```
My $fh=”file1.txt”;

my @lines = read_file($fh);

while ( my $line = shift @lines) {

      next unless ($line =~ m/def/);

      last; # this code will write till end of file i.e. dqq

}

append_file('file2.txt', @lines);
```

Comment: You don't appear to have asked a question. We're not going to write your code for you.

Comment: i added what i know

Comment: `perl -ne '(/def ->\[/ .. /]/) =~ /(^|^1|E0)$/ or print' f1.txt > f2.txt`

Answer (score 0):

here it is

```
while(<DATA>){
print $_ if /sff/ ... /ghi/
}


__DATA__
abc 
def ->[
    sff 
    l1
    l2
    ghi 
]
dqq
```

Answer (score 0):

my $fh1 = "file1.txt";

use File::Slurp;

$search1 = "start";

$search2 = "end";

## open (WRITE,'>>',$new);

open (fh,"<","$fh1");

while()
{

push @array,$_ if/$search1/../$search2/;

}

close(fh);

append_file('file2.txt',@array);